Flutter pushing a page onto Context after google sign in
Just starting a flutter personal project. I'm working on onboarding pages in a Flutter application that will come up after a new user is made. There are presently two ways to make a user: email/password or Google sign-in. My onboarding pages can correctly be pushed on with Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/onboarding'); . However, when I try to my same flow with GoogleSignin, it decides to change the page before it is able to push the new page on. This makes it lose context and it gives this error.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
#0      State.context.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:951:9)
#1      State.context (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:957:6)
#2      _LoginPageState._handleGoogleSignIn (package:silo_app/pages/auth/login_page.dart:64:29)
<asynchronous suspension>

Here is the code on how I am handling google sign in and then how I am rendering my pages for my home or authpages.

  void _handleGoogleSignIn() async {
    bool isNewUser = false;

    try {
      isNewUser = await GoogleSignInService().signInWithGoogle(context);
    } catch (error) {
      print("Google sign-in failed: $error");
    } finally {
      if (mounted) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      } else {
        print("not mounted so it can't be popped");
      }
      if (isNewUser) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/onboarding');
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
      }
    }
  }

class GoogleSignInService {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<bool> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    print("Start of 3rd party signin");
    try {
      print('Signing in with Google');
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await _googleSignIn.signIn();

      if (googleSignInAccount == null) {
        print('Google sign-in was cancelled.');
        return false;
      }

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
          await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      );

      final UserCredential credentials =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCredential);

      User? user = credentials.user;

      if (user != null) {
        print('User signed in successfully: ${user.uid}');
        DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Users")
            .doc(user.uid)
            .get();

        if (!userDoc.exists) {
          print('User does not exist in Firestore, creating user...');
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("Users")
              .doc(user.uid)
              .set({
            "email": user.email,
            "username": user.displayName ?? user.email!.split("@")[0],
            "dateCreated": DateTime.now(),
            "uid": user.uid,
          });

          print("User created successfully");
          return true;
        } else {
          print('User already exists, navigating to home...');
          return false;
        }
      }
      return false;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
}

class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF010922),
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return HomePage();
            } else {
              return LoginOrRegisterPage();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}

I suspect that the issue is with how context and widgets are getting changed based on the streamBuilder. Cause that will automatically change when it gets the signing from google. But then, why does it work for normal firebase register? and what are solutions to prevent the widget from exiting before my code has finished executing.
I making the service return a variable on if it is a new user or not, and then dealing with routes in the page that is calling the Google sign in service. I thought this would keep the widget mounted, but it seems like it immediately switches to the homepage when the async signInWithCredential goes through. I was wondering what the best approach for this would be.
Thanks for any help!
